# Revenue data type in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am setting up company pages. One of the fields is 'Revenue'. So this can vary from $0 to i guess hundreds of billions. So this field should have a bigint data type? Or is there a better way to store revenue in the database? Using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`DECIMAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html) data type.

Answer (score 0):

I would use bigint and store your revenue figures in pennies rather than using decimals. Then you will avoid rounding issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try Numeric or decimal. The **DECIMAL** and **NUMERIC** types store exact numeric data values. These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data.

check this out: [MySQL data types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)